# Missing required parameter for [Route: clients.show] [URI: clients/{client}] [Missing parameter: client]

Tags: php, laravel

When I click on sales index page, the following error is shown:

> Missing required parameter for [Route: clients.show] [URI:
> clients/{client}] [Missing parameter: client].

Here is my `salescontroller` index function code:

```
public function index()
     {

      $user_id=helper::getDistId();
      $sales = Sale::where('dist_id','=', $user_id)->latest()->paginate(25);

      return view('sales.index', compact('sales'));

   }`
```

Comment: Can you share you view code too???

Answer (score 0):

Controller should look like this

```
public function index($user_id){
    $user_id=helper::getDistId();
    $sales = Sale::where('dist_id','=', $user_id)->latest()->paginate(25);
    return view('sales.index', compact('sales'));
}
```

And Route in web.php :

```
Route::get('/clients/{client}', [SalesController::class, 'index'])->name('clients.show');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Client index page there must be a `href="{{route('clients.show')}}"`  inside this you should pass the client id.   like `href="{{route('clients.show', $client_id)}}"`  where `$client_id` refers to the id of the client which you want to show.

if its inside foreach loop  then may be you can do

```
@foreach($sales as $sale)
  href="{{route('client.show', $sale->id)}}"
@endforeach
```

hope you get the point.